# Could not find installable ISAM with excel 16.0

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to load an excel file to datagridview however I keep getting the error "could not find installable ISAM." I tried what other posts said about changing where I put my single quotes but I still keep getting that error. This is what I have right now.

```
 conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source='C:\Users\test.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 16.0;';")
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you have the `ACE.OLEDB.16.0` provider installed? if so, in which *flavor* (x86 or x64)? What is your application bitness? What is its target platform?

Comment: I have it installed as x86. Application bitness is 32 and target CPU is x86

Comment: Do you also have MS Office installed? In this case, what version and bitness? In the meanwhile, set your target platform to `AnyCPU` and deselect the `Prefer 32-bit` option if enabled. If you also have the `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider, try this one, too. Change `Excel 16.0` in `Excel 12.0 Xml`. Note that you have redundant semicolon at the end of your connection string and the path is not exactly valid. Unless it's there just for show, move the file to a different location (maybe in `Bin\Debug` for now, so you can access it with `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "test.xlsx")`).

Comment: I changed it from 16.0 to 12.0 and it worked. idk why 16.0 wouldn't work. I have it as my reference. but thanks for the help

Comment: If you follow the previous *instructions* , you'll manage to use both, provided that both are actually installed (correctly). It's not clear what you changed in the end and what *I have it as my reference* means (since you don't reference these providers, you just specify them in connection strings).

Answer (score 0):

You need install Microsoft Access Runtime

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-microsoft-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9

And make sure your project is match de architecture of your ACE Runtime.

I'll just recommend to use OLEDB.12.0 as this and remove excess of '

```
OleDbConnection conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\test.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;';")
```